# Node.js: Writing to system files with fs.writeFileSync

Tags: node.js, file-io, fs, file-writing

I am trying to write to a system file under `/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget` with `fs.writeFileSync` but when writing `""` as the contents, the file remains unchanged (with original contents in tact) and results in

```
Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, write
    at Object.writeSync (fs.js:581:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1275:26)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/sterling/ip-kvm-interface/app.js:249:6)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at /opt/sterling/ip-kvm-interface/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  errno: -16,
  syscall: 'write',
  code: 'EBUSY'
}
```

when writing some other contents. Permissions for the destination write file are 777.

Is `fs.writeFileSync` incapable of writing to files under `sys` or am I missing something else?

Using `fsuser /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/kvm-gadget/UDC` returns nothing (even when Node process is running) and `lsof | grep /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/kvm-gadget/UDC` also returns nothing.

Am I going to have to `spawn` an `echo` process to get this to work (not preferred but crossed my mind - since not sure how I would convert it to synchronous task)?

Comment: Does `Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked` not explain that the resource is in use and can't be written to by your process?

Comment: Are you able to do these writes as the same user as your process from a shell?

Comment: @jfriend00 the entire extent of the error message is included in the OP

Comment: @Joe yes I can and without sudo

Comment: I just meant that the error message seems self explanatory.  The resource is busy or locked.  You will have to figure out why.

Comment: @jfriend00 would I be able to write to the file (using echo) in shell per Joe's suggestion if the resource was busy?

Comment: Probably not.  I don't know what OS you are on, but aren't there OS tools that will let you see what else may be using that file?  Does your own process do something with  a USB device that could be causing this?

Comment: @jfriend00 my process does do something with USB but I CAN edit the file while it's "in use"

Comment: Can edit the file, how?  From a separate editor app?

Comment: `echo "" > file` results in a persistent change - using raspbian buster

Comment: Perhaps some custom `mode` or `flag` option to `fs.writeFileSync()` would make it more likely to work for you?  As you can see in [the source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1299), `fs.writeFileSync()` defaults to `mode: 0o666, flag: 'w' ` when you don't pass it anything.  Run some experiments and try different modes or flags.

Comment: @jfriend00 It appears that the mode only refers to the permissions used to access the file for which `0o666` should suffice and `0o777` does not either. the `flags` refer (in my case) to `'w'`: write or `'a'`: append for which I would  need the former. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please leave some of your code. Maybe I can hep you.

Comment: @AmerllicA I can post later today if you don't concur with the answer I provided. I.e. if the answer does not match the issue you anticipated, let me know

Comment: Dear bro @SterlingButters, If you think it is the right answer so it is, no doubt. but ticking your own answer doesn't return the bounty to your account reputation. I leave an upvote to your question an upvote to your answer. hope it motivates you to keep going on Stack Overflow. For more information contact me `amerllica@gmail.com`

Comment: @AmerllicA yes it's kind of unfortunately it works that way - thank you for the up votes (Def makes me regret the bounty less)

Comment: Dear @SterlingButters, Do not regret, please give your email or send an email to my email address that I wrote it on above comment. I wanna say a private thing to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2459

> ```
> Are there undocumented limitations to fs.writeFileSync that I am unaware of?
> ```
>
> Nothing specific to fs.writeFileSync(), you can get the same error
>   with a plain C program.
>
> /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget is not a real file, it's a communication
>   channel with the kernel's usb gadget driver. It's that driver that is
>   returning the error.
>
> (I could point you to the line of code if you're really interested.
>   It's drivers/usb/gadget/configfs.c in the kernel source tree in any
>   case.)